# How can i get the input of an TextInputLayout as Shared preferences and print them on another activity?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use Shared Preferences and send my data into another activity. When I click on the registration textview the application crashes and I get the error message

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.EditText com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.getEditText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.irongym.RegistrationActivity.onCreate(RegistrationActivity.java:45)
```

In other cases where I was using EditText, I used a similar way and it was working. I think that the way I try to get the data is wrong because now I am using TextInputLayout

This is my RegistrationActivity.java (onCreate)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences file = getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);

    TextInputLayout nameField = findViewById(R.id.TextInputEditText);
    TextInputLayout passwordField = findViewById(R.id.PasswordInputEditText);
    TextInputLayout phoneField = findViewById(R.id.PhoneInputEditText);

    String na = file.getString("name", "");
    String pas = file.getString("password2", "");
    String ph = file.getString("phone", "");

    nameField.getEditText().setText(na); // This is line 45 from the error i get
    passwordField.getEditText().setText(pas);
    phoneField.getEditText().setText(ph);
```

This is my RegistrationActivity.java button onclick

```
public void confirmInput(View v) {
    SharedPreferences file = getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = file.edit();

    TextInputLayout nameField = findViewById(R.id.TextInputEditText);
    TextInputLayout passwordField = findViewById(R.id.PasswordInputEditText);
    TextInputLayout phoneField = findViewById(R.id.PhoneInputEditText);

    String name = nameField.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String password2 = passwordField.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String phone = phoneField.getEditText().getText().toString();

    editor.putString("name", name);
    editor.putString("password2", password2);
    editor.putString("phone", phone);

    editor.commit();
    
    Intent in = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

This is my ProfileActivity.java where the data will be displayed

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

    SharedPreferences file = getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);

    String we = file.getString("weight", "no-weight");
    String he = file.getString("height", "no-height");
    String na = file.getString("name", "no-name");
    String ph = file.getString("phone", "no-phone");
    String ps = file.getString("password2", "no-password");

    TextView tvWe = findViewById(R.id.tvWeight);
    TextView tvHe = findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
    TextView tvNa = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvPh = findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
    TextView tvPs = findViewById(R.id.tvPassword);

    tvWe.setText(we);
    tvHe.setText(he);
    tvNa.setText(na);
    tvPh.setText(ph);
    tvPs.setText(ps);

    binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call `setContentView()` in RegistrationActivity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, because you haven't called `setContentView` there are no `View`s in your Activity. So

```
TextInputLayout nameField = findViewById(R.id.TextInputEditText);
```

returns *null* because that `View` wasn't found. Because `nameField` is *null*, you can't call this method on it:

```
nameField.getEditText() // crashes with a NullPointerException
```

And that's basically what the error is telling you:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
Attempt to invoke virtual method
'android.widget.EditText com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.getEditText()'
on a null object reference
```

You tried to call the `getEditText()` method on something that's meant to be a `TextInputLayout`, but it's actually *null*. You just need to find out why!